# cannot upload photos from picasa via facebook uploader

Tags: picasa, facebook

I have a problem with Facebook uploader in Picasa

How can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is a known facebook bug (see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/334259423289252/?browse=search_4f794cd7b40245f34034966) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/365176053526578)).

As a workaround, you might want to try uploading the pictures as private. If that does not work, then there is nothing that you can do until facebook fixes the bug/